# How to get the value of the matrix socket via scriptsNode

Tags: animation-nodes

I am new to AN, I want to get the value of the matrix socket output as below in the shot, but it doesn't work, I don't know how to fix it. Could you help me?

[image: Script Node]

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: does this help?: http://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/subprograms/script.html

Comment: Thanks Jacques Lucke! why the consol tell me "the socket list type has no value attributes",I want to get the value of the list type,can you help me?Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When creating a subprogram in Animation Nodes (eg. *Script Node*), you are only defining what that subprogram do, in order to actually use it, you have to **Invoke** the subprogram. You can invoke a subprogram by adding an *Invoke Subprogram Node* pointing to the required subprogram, this can be done through the *Subprograms* panel in the *Add Node menu* where all subprograms are listed:

[image: Add Subprograms]

To get the value of some data in the script, you add an input with the same type, in your case, it is a *Matrix List* and input the data to it. A variable that carry the input data is automatically created with the name of the input, in our case, it is called `MatrixList`, you can use this variable to do what ever you want with the input data. For instance, you can print the list and its length as follows:

[image: Node Tree]